# How to generate images of web pages in a high performance environment?

Tags: c#, .net, chromium, webautomation, puppeteer-sharp

I am trying to generate images of web pages in under a second in a server-side environment.  The requests could come in parallel, at the same time from the web. To that end, I am using [Puppeteer-Sharp](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp) library which works pretty well.  On the back end its using Chromium to load the page and then screenshot it.

The problem is that it takes a while to get started.  For instance, note the timings (from my pc) from the readme.md sample code:

```
var options = new new LaunchOptions {Headless = true, ExecutablePath = @"c:\foo\chrome.exe"};
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options).Result;    //  ~500ms
var page = browser.NewPageAsync().Result;                     //  ~215ms
var webPage = page.GoToAsync("http://www.google.com").Result; //  ~500ms
var screenshot = page.ScreenshotAsync(outputFile);            
screenshot.wait();                                            //  ~300ms
```

As you can see, it easily goes over a second.  I don't know how Chromium works internally, so I have a couple of questions pertaining to solutions that I am thinking of.

1. Is the `PuppeteerSharp.Browser` object thread-safe and/or re-entrant?  Can I use the same browser object from different threads? I am thinking not, because it's tied to a specific instance of Chromium in memory.
2. If I cut out `.LaunchAsync` and `.NetPageAsync` from every request that will significantly speed up the operation.  Will pool of `PuppeteerSharp.Browser` objects work?  For instance, I can pre-allocate 5 of these and execute `.NetPageAsync`on them.  Then the incoming requests would use the objects from the pool.  Is that a viable approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although there are still [many improvements going on](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp/pull/925), Puppeteer-Sharp is thread-safe. To improve loading performance, there are a few approaches you can take.

**Launch one browser and then connect to it**

You can launch one (real) browser and then use the `ConnectAsync` method to connect to it.

```cs
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = false,
});

var theBrowser1 = await Puppeteer.ConnectAsync(new ConnectOptions { BrowserWSEndpoint = browser.WebSocketEndpoint });
var theBrowser2 = await Puppeteer.ConnectAsync(new ConnectOptions { BrowserWSEndpoint = browser.WebSocketEndpoint });
var page1 = await theBrowser1.NewPageAsync();
var page2 = await theBrowser2.NewPageAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(
    page1.GoToAsync("https://www.stackoverflow.com"),
    page2.GoToAsync("https://serverfault.com/")
);
```

I know that code is not running in parallel, but you'll get the idea about reusing the same browser.

**Create new pages on the same browser**

If you are using [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl), you shouldn't have any issues creating new pages from different threads using the same browser.

```cs
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = false,
});

var urls = new string[]
{
    "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
};

await Task.WhenAll(
    urls.Select(url => Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        return page.GoToAsync(url);
    })));
```

Again, this example is just to give you an idea of how this could be accomplished.

**Pages queue**

There is one user who created a queue of X pages (for x from 0 to X => NewPage) and then he would grab pages from that queue. You can see the [example here](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp/issues/331#issuecomment-433536896).